# How to return single list of answers (instead of multiple individual answers) in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, combinations

I have a prolog definition that returns multiple answers. I would like instead of this, to return a single list containing all possible answers.

E.g.

```
alpha;
beta;
gamma;
delta;
```

to

```
[alpha, beta, gamma, delta];
```

How can this be done in prolog?

Comment: What's the definition look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that depending on your specific need, `findall/3` might not be a fit:

Consider the predicate `test/2 : test(+L, -E)` that unifies `E` with members of `L` that are free variables:

```
test(L, E) :-
    member(E, L),
    var(E).
```

Now, let's say you want to find all the free variables of a list by using this predicate (note: if you really wanna do that, that's not the right way, it's just to point out a `findall/3` behaviour):

```
?- findall(X, test([A, 3, C], X), Xs).
Xs = [_G32, _G29].
```

`findall/3` answers you with a good answer, but modulus a variable renaming!

```
?- bagof(X, test([A, 3, C], X), Xs).
Xs = [A, C].
```

or

```
?- setof(X, test([A, 3, C], X), Xs).
Xs = [A, C].
```

do the trick though.

I'm not sure whether what I said here applies to other Prolog systems than SWI-Prolog.

Here is the corresponding [doc page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.29%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html%27%29%29).

Comment: Very interesting and useful. I like this

Comment: This is not specific to SWI.  All 3 are ISO built-ins. But `bagof/3` and `setof/3` have some more details to explore...

Comment: this is wrong answer to the question as asked. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By using `findall`. You have `somepred(X)` which gives you the answers as you specified. Now try and run `findall(X,somepred(X),List)` to see `List` unified with a list of all answers.

***edit:*** Using `setof` or `bagof` instead of `findall` is wrong in the context of the question, as asked.

`setof` is obviously wrong as it skips valid solutions that happen to be duplicates. `bagof` *fails* when there are no solutions, whilst `findall` correctly *"returns"* an empty list `[]` (as requested by the OP). Oh, and both `bagof` and `setof` *backtrack* on alternative bindings for free variables, whereas the OP clearly asked for *one list of solutions* to be *"returned"*, i.e. ***no backtracking***. To wit:

```
?- [user].
|: test(L,E):- member(E,L),var(E).
|: 
% user://2 compiled 0.00 sec, 124 bytes

Yes
?- findall(X, (test([A,3,A],X) , member(A,[1,2]) )   , Xs).

X = _G546
A = _G536
Xs = [1, 2, 1, 2] ;

No
?- bagof(X, (test([A,3,A],X) , member(A,[1,2]) )     , Xs).

X = _G534
A = 1
Xs = [1, 1] ;

X = _G534
A = 2
Xs = [2, 2] ;

No
?-
```

but the OP asked for *"single list containing all possible answers"* to be returned.

***edit:*** A list of all answers when there are no answers is an empty list.

Comment: Oh yeah, almost forgot about findall(). Thank you very much

Comment: regarding @WillNess edit, it must be precised that bagof and setof have a control mechanism (`^`) not to backtrack if needed, and that as precise semantics weren't given in the OP, the "wrong claims" are not properly argumented regarding the fail on no solution.

Comment: @Mog well I just assumed that when "one list containing all possible solutions" is wanted, the empty list naturally represents the list of no solutions.

Comment: @Mog you mean it is natural to expect of a list-returning computation to fail instead of returning an empty list? Usually we get a list of results, then we inspect whether it's empty or not. That's how lists are usually used, I thought.